# Evaluation time of spec/valid? grows exponentially

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I am using `clojure.spec` to parse a DSL. Unfortunately, the computation time for testing if something conforms with my spec seems to grow exponentially. I would like to understand why, and how to address it.

This is what the spec looks like:

```
(spec/def ::settings map?)

(spec/def ::header (spec/spec
                    (spec/cat :prefix #{:begin-example}
                              :label string?
                              :settings (spec/? ::settings))))

(def end-block [:end-example])

(spec/def ::not-end (partial not= end-block))

(spec/def ::end #{end-block})

(spec/def ::block (spec/cat
                   :header ::header
                   :data (spec/* ::not-end)
                   :suffix ::end))

(spec/def ::form (spec/alt :block ::block
                           :form any?))

(spec/def ::forms (spec/* ::form))
```

In order to exercise the spec, I wrote a small function that produces *valid* data for the spec, and a size parameter to control the size of the data:

```
(defn make-sample-data [size]
  (transduce
   (comp (take size)
         cat)
   conj
   []
   (repeat [:a 1 :b :c [:begin-example "a" {:indent 4}] :d :e [:end-example] 9])))

(make-sample-data 1)
;; => [:a 1 :b :c [:begin-example "a" {:indent 4}] :d :e [:end-example] 9]

(make-sample-data 2)
;; => [:a 1 :b :c [:begin-example "a" {:indent 4}] :d :e [:end-example] 9 :a 1 :b :c [:begin-example "a" {:indent 4}] :d :e [:end-example] 9]
```

Now I am executing this code:

```
(dotimes [i 13]
  (assert (time (spec/valid? ::forms (make-sample-data i)))))
```

which produces the following output:

```
"Elapsed time: 0.077095 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 0.333636 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 0.864481 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 2.198994 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 4.432004 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 9.026142 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 17.709151 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 35.201316 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 73.178516 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 138.93966 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 288.349616 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 569.471181 msecs"
"Elapsed time: 1162.944497 msecs"
```

It appears to me that for every step of the size parameter, the computation time doubles.

**My question is:** How can I modify my spec so that validation time is linear with the size of my data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm *guessing* the performance issue comes from a combination of greedy, branching regex specs with `any?` predicates.

The use of `any?` in the `s/alt :form` regex branch stood out to me. I suppose spec might be evaluating each branch of the `s/alt` greedily/exhaustively and then backtracking, and `any?` matches everything *including* values that match your `:block` branch. (Notice the spec conforms the same regardless of whether `:form any?` branch is defined before or after `:block` branch.)

If you can use a more specific predicate than `any?` in your top-level `s/alt :form` branch, you should see a big improvement. I inlined the spec definitions for brevity:

```
(s/def ::forms
  (s/*
    (s/alt :block
           (s/cat :header (s/spec
                            (s/cat :prefix #{:begin-example}
                                   :label string?
                                   :settings (s/? map?)))
                  :data (s/* #(not= % [:end-example]))
                  :suffix #{[:end-example]})
           :form
           (s/nonconforming ;; don't tag results
             (s/or :keyword keyword?
                   :number number?)))))

(time (s/valid? ::forms (make-sample-data 1000)))
"Elapsed time: 84.637513 msecs"
=> true
```

Note that allowing a collection predicate (e.g. `coll?`, `vector?`) to that `:form` branch degrades performance just like `any?`. I suppose this is because the same values are matching both branches of the `s/alt`.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that replacing `any?` by something more specific that does not overlap with the `:block` spec results in a huge improvement. So your explanation about spec evaluating both branches makes sense.